# Prove that $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, set-theory

**1)** Earlier, I was asked to provide a counterexample for: $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$

- My attempt: Consider the function $f: R → R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$. Let $A_1=[0, \infty)$ and $A_2=(-\infty,0]$. Then $A_1 \cap A_2 = \{0\}$ so $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = \{0\}$. However, $f(A_1) = f(A_2) = [0,\infty)$, so $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) = [0,\infty)$. This happened because two different elements in the domain are mapped to the same element in the range.

**2)** Then, I was asked to prove: $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$

- My attempt:

  1. let $x \in f(A_1 \cap A_2)$
  2. That implies that $x \in f(A_1)$ and $x \in f(A_2)$
  3. Since $x \in f(A_1)$ and $x \in f(A_2)$, we can conclude that $x \in A_1 \cap A_2$, which also means that $x \in A_1$ and $x \in A_2$
  4. Thus $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$

---

I would really appreciate the feedback on the latter proof *mainly*. Thank you!

Comment: `\infty` gives you the infinity symbol $\infty$.

Comment: Your second step in part 2 is incorrect. From $x\in f(A_1\cap A_2)$ you cannot deduce that $x\in f(A_1)$ and $x\in f(A_2)$. That would be the conclusion you draw from $x\in f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)$, which is a different statement (in fact, your desired conclusion).

Comment: Step 3 in part 2 is likewise wrong (doesn't even make sense). And step $4$ is not even a grammatical statement as currently written.

Comment: For the first, an easier example is the function $f=1$ defined on $\{0,1\}$ Then let $A_1 = \{1\}, A_0=\{0\}$ and note that $f(A_k) = \{1\}$ but $f(A_0 \cap A_1) = \emptyset$.

Comment: For the second, note that if $A \subset B$ then $f(A) \subset f(B)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin second step is indeed correct, see my answer.

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor I *know* it is incorrect. I said so. Why are you pinging me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the $f$-image of any $A$ that is a subset of the domain for $f$, as $f(A) := \{f(x):x\in A\}$ .

> $f(A)$ is the set of all elements mapped by $f$ from the elements of $A$.

Then for any $A_1, A_2$ that are subsets of this domain: $$\begin{align}f(A_1\cap A_2) &=\{f(x):x\in A_1\cap A_2\}\\ &=\{f(x): x\in A_1\cap x\in A_2\}\\&=\{f(x):x\in A_1\}\cap\{f(x):x\in A_2\}\\&=f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)\end{align}$$

> $f(A_1\cap A_2)$ is the set of all elements mapped by $f$ from ...*blah-blah-blah*...  and therefore $f(A_1\cap A_2)$ is exactly the intersection of $f(A_1)$ and $f(A_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$ x \in f(A_1 \cap A_2) $

$ \exists $ $ y \in A_1 \cap A_2 $, such that $ x = f(y)$

Since $ y \in A_1 \cap A_2  $, implies $y \in A_1,$  $y \in   A_2 $

Hence, $ x \in f(A_1)$, $ x \in f(A_2)$

Therefore, $ x \in f(A_1) \cap f(A_1)$